# CSS - How to overlap elements over everything but each other? (No margin/padding etc)

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation bar and I would like it to have pure CSS dropdown menus, the problem with this is that in order for them to not overlap the rest of the page you have to set them to `position: absolute`, however this causes all the links to occupy the same space. Giving them individual margins will space them out but as they occupy the same virtual space only the last link is actually clickable.

HTML:

```
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbutton" id="navbuttonselected">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="navbutton">About Me</a>
            <div id="programs">
                <a href="programs.html" class="navbutton">Programs</a>
                    <li><a class="navbutton" style="margin-top:0px;">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbutton" style="margin-top:62px;">Test 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbutton" style="margin-top:124px;">Test 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbutton" style="margin-top:186px;">Test 4</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00A2E8;
}

.navbutton
{
    color: #BBBBBB;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 45px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: relative;
}

#programs
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#programs > li
{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#programs:hover > li
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Is there any way to make them overlap everything but each other, so that the links are clickable but not moving the whole page down? Preferably a solution without JQuery/Javascript please. Thanks!

Comment: Your markup is broken. Unordered lists (ULs) must consist of list items (LIs). You may want to use  a nested list: ``<ul><li>1</li><li><ul><li>2.1</li><li>2.2</li></ul></li><li>3</li></ul>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i think i may have figured this problem out. all i did was add a z-index of 1 to the .navbutton element and it worked. all the other css i did not modify at all.

```
   .navbutton
{
    color:#BBBBBB;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:45px;
    padding-top:17px;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1; /* this is the rule too add */
}
```

I hope that helps :-)

Comment: I can't believe the solution was so simple. Thanks so much, now I won't have to use any JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

```
<div style="z-index: 1;">Top</div>
<div style="z-index: 0;">Middle</div>
<div style="z-index: -1;">Bottom</div>
```